# Is there a more eloquent way of doing these MySQL queries?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making 4 individual queries to a MySQL DB, all of which are identical except the WHERE parameters. 2 of which are:

```
$totalInvites = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT code FROM invites"));
$usedInvites = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT code FROM invites WHERE used IS NOT NULL"));
```

Is there a way of doing the $totalInvites query and from the returned table, do the WHERE call without doing another query?

If that's confusing, this is an example of what I mean:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT code FROM invites");
$totalInvites = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$usedInvites = mysqli_num_rows($query /*WHERE used IS NOT NULL*/);
```

I know that's not proper syntax but that's what I was trying say.

Comment: What do you want? Counts by code of used and unused?

Comment: Essentially, but in 1 query if possible. It works the way I'm doing it now with multiple queries, but want to see if there's a cleaner way of doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want counts then retrieving the entire database and throwing out the results is not really a good idea. Instead jus task for a count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, used
  GROUP BY used
```

This will give you up to two rows, one count for those that are used and one that isn't presuming `used` has only `NULL` or a single non-null value.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use as little SQL as possible:

```
SELECT if(used is null, 0, 1) AS used, code
FROM invites
```

And parse result in PHP according to what you need

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
(SELECT code FROM invites) total
(SELECT code FROM invites WHERE used IS NOT NULL) used
```